# Use all wordpress functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I need to write API for **WordPress** site to support mobile application. But I need use basic functions from mobile device, like create a post for example, I send content, title, image data (all post data) with HTTP POST to API from my mobile application.

i don't want code separate database requests and study DB organization. I want simply call something like `createPost` **WordPress** method from my API.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**WordPress XMLRPC^**](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) is what you need. It allows you to remote control a WordPress installation.

**PS**: *Google 'wordpress remote control'.*

Comment: OK, how can I create new post with image with this lib?

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko Upload Media with `wp.uploadFile`. Then you get the URL of the image and use it in your post body. Unfortunately, I haven't updated that script for WP 3.5. I'm currently very busy with some projects but by autumn, I'll have the updated version with custom post types too. PS: That's my site :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for this lib. I am working with version 3.5.1 now. And when I include `require_once("xmlrpc.php")` I receive error 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function load_textdomain() in /home/.../wp-admin/includes/admin.php on line 13` how can I fix it?

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko You need a XMLRPC client to communication. wpremotecontrol.com is my site and there's one there. http://code.google.com/p/php-ixr/ is the one used by WP. You can't include anything of WP. You either implement the XMLRPC client yourself or buy mine :) No other choice.

Comment: Do you mean that is exists only one solution, yours and it's not free?

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko No, there's 2: the 2nd is to write your own ... But keep google-ing for it. Just bookmark my site today. You'll come back, they all do :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33004/discussion-between-dmytro-zarezenko-and-codeangry)